# tabular configuration snakemake

Tags: pandas, snakemake

I try to build a Snakemake pipeline where the processed files and their paramters are definied in a [seperate table](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/configuration.html).

In my minimal example the folder structure would look like this.

```
├── data
│   ├── name1
│   ├── name2
│   ├── name3
│   └── name4
├── output
├── samples.tsv
└── Snakefile
```

I would like to copy varying amounts of file "name1", "name2", and "name3" (not "name4") to the output folder. The amounts are definiend in in the sample.tsv.

```
fileName    parameter
name1   4
name2   6
name3   7
```

I guess the basic structure of the Snakefile should look a bit like this

```
import pandas as pd
samples = pd.read_table("samples.tsv").set_index("fileName", drop=False)

rule copy:
    input:
        "data/{<file name X>}"
    output:
        "output/{<file name X>}_cut"
    shell:
        "head -n {parameter of X} {input} > {output} "
```

But I have no idea how to parse the information from "samples" to the rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand Dimitry's answer, you probably want to add to your rule a lambda function that links each filename to its parameter(s) given in the sample sheet. E.g.:

```
import pandas as pd
samples = pd.read_table("samples.tsv").set_index("fileName", drop=False)

rule all:
    input:
        expand('output/{fileName}_cut', fileName= samples.fileName),

rule copy:
    input:
        "data/{fileName}"
    output:
        "output/{fileName}_cut"
    params:
        n= lambda wc: samples[samples.fileName == wc.fileName].parameter.iloc[0],
    shell:
        "head -n {params.n} {input} > {output}"
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the rule `all` as the first rule in your file:

```py
rule all:
    input: expand("output/{filenameX}_cut", filenameX=samples)
```

This rule would collect all required targets as the goal of your pipeline, then Snakemake would automatically assign an instance of the `rule copy` for each individual file.